# Eclipse disable only auto angle brackets

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time I go to put an angle bracket (<>) in for a less than sign in Eclipse Java, Eclipse auto-closes it. I'm fine with this feature for parentheses and square brackets, but it gets in the way with angle brackets and doesn't even really make sense. I've tried to disable it, but the only option disables square brackets and parentheses as well. Is there a setting or other method to disable *only* angle brackets?

Comment: That should not be happening.  For some reason Eclipse might think you are editing HTML or XML and not Java source. Did you change the file type bindings in your preferences?

Comment: I checked just now and it looks like the bindings are correct (says *.java is bound to the java editor)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Eclipse auto-closes '<' when it follows text that looks like a class name so it might be generic.

So if I type:

```
List<
```

I get auto-close because 'List' looks like a class name (starts with an upper case letter and follows the rules for a class name), but if I type:

```
list<
```

I don't get auto-close (does not start with upper case).

There does not appear to be a separate setting to stop this.

Comment: That seems like it was the problem. I'm working on a short lab, and the temp I was using to hold coordinate values was just "X" and "Y". After testing using lower case though, it's working as expected. Thanks for the help!